# Linux Kubuntu: HDD is not detected in file explorer Dolphin

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, hard-drive, ssd

I have two drives: SSD (500GB) and HDD (1TB). However my system seems to only detect the SSD. And I don't save files on HDD.

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
```

command gives this:

[image]

Looks like the `sdb` thing is the HDD.

However Dolphin doesn't detect it and I'm currently seemingly only use my SSD:

In left sidebar of Dolphin:

[image]

What do I do to be able to start using the HDD?

Comment: Has the drive been formatted?  Is it mounted?

Comment: @Nmath It's screwed to case and connected to motherboard and PSU. I did the same with my 2.5 SSD. Apart from that I did nothing

Comment: If it's a new drive you might need to format it. It also needs to be mounted. You can use KDE partition manager to format the disk. Keep in mind that formatting will erase the disk. If you need more information about formatting and mounting, you can search here using those terms.